# Swift UIImageView Cut Off

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, firebase-storage

So I'm having a really strange issue.

I have an `ImageView` inside a `TableViewCell`.  The constraints are set to all 4 sides.  When I download an image from firebase I get this weird indentation on the left-hand side (this is for multiple images of different sizes).

I've tried Scale to Fill, Aspect Fill, setting the height and width, setting the cells inset to 0, plus some other things I can't even remember.

Then I decided to set the image as a static image and it displayed the image perfectly.

In this photo you can see the static image in the background and the image loaded from firebase being placed on top.

[image]

[image]

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cells...
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath) as! LocationHeaderCell
        let locationImageRef = storage.child("locationImages/"+(documentId)+".jpg")
        // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
        locationImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred! Display Default image
                print("Error - unable to download image: \(error)")
            } else {
                // Data for "locationImages/(locationId).jpg" is returned
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    case 1:
```

Any idea what this issue could be?  Going a little bonkers here lol

Comment: if you have properly set the constraints, imageview.contentmode = .scaleaspectfit should work. you can check the view hierarchy in the debugger and select the imageView to see the constraints and views frame. I suggest you also read this article by Use your loaf on Stretching, redrawing,  and positioning. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/

Comment: set imageView.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: Tried imageview.contentmode = .scaleaspectfit and setting the imageview clip to bounds to true.  Both did not work...I'm adding a screenshot to show the constraints and the hierarchy

Comment: Calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` in `cellForRowAt` is bad.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni the image wouldn't load until I scrolled the view.  where do you suggest i call it?

Comment: does changing the content mode change the image? UITableViewCell by default has a UIImageView named imageView, perhaps rename your custom cell's Image View. Note that the default imageView for UITableViewCell also has padding to left of the image view.

Comment: @Ercell0 actually no the image never changed when i changed the content mode

Comment: @pmanning try renaming your class property 'imageView' to 'locationImageView' or overriding it from it's super class UITableViewCell.

Comment: Tried renaming...going to try a new tableVC to see if this is a bug.  Literally have a near identical tableVC that is working fine with the same set up

Comment: Nope same issue - now starting to think it could be how I download and present the image?

Comment: Ayiyiyi - found it! So i didn't realize I was setting it to the imageView.image...thanks @Ercell0

Comment: @pmanning its the simple things in life that will overburden you if you let them.

Comment: haha very very true